# Fill jQuery UI selectable by AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-selectable

I am working on filling a jQuery selectable via AJAX call. I have prepared server side API, which has been tested will return serialized jason object.

I have declared the selectable at client side

```
<ol id="selectable"></ol>
```

Then I have a button will trigger the AJAX call to get data.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/XXX/XXX,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    //error: OnAjaxError,
    success: function (data) {

    }
});

button.onclick = function () {
    $("#selectable").selectable({
      //here to fill the selectable list
    });                
}
```

I searched via Google but most of the case I found were predefined the list at client side.

Then how I render the list after I got my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a loop of your returned data from the server and build `li` tags dynamically into your `ol` tag and then apply the plugin.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/XXX/XXX,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    //error: OnAjaxError,
    success: function (data) {
       $.each(data,function(){
         $("#selectable").append('<li>'+this.Name+'</li>');
         //here I am using data.item change it to whatever your server is returning and what you have to show in the li tags
       });
       $("#selectable").selectable(); //apply the plugin
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, first thank you very much! My server side API returns List<TreeNode> as object. TreeNode has name, id etc. Whatever I put data.item.name or data.name, none of them worked. Any hint?

Comment: It works now, see posted updates! Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it works for you, Also you can use `this.Name` inside the loop. `this` would mean the current object in the loop.I have updated my answer with this code